# Unable to proceed after setting cookie in a middleware

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm unable to proceed the request after setting cookie in a middleware

```js
const somemiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // do stuff
  req.cookie('accessToken', token, { signed: true, httpOnly: true, etc... });
  console.log('it should run this line after setting cookie right?');
  next();
}

router.post('/blah', somemiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  // I expect req.signedCookies to be the token assigned from above
});
```

The terminal shows that the req ends after `req.cookie` and it does not proceed to the console log and rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `res.cookie()`, not `req.cookie()`.

You read cookies from the request.  You set cookies on the response.

If you put a `try/catch` around it, you should see an exception and I'm surprised there wasn't anything about that in your server logs.